# dependancies not found error after running command npm run serve in vue

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have cloned one of my vue project from git to my another laptop. I have ran npm install.

But after running npm run serve I am getting the following error -

These dependencies were not found:

```
* core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime.js
* core-js/modules/es.error.to-string.js in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js core-js/modules/es.error.to-string.js
```

Why is this occuring ?

**Note :** I have run npm install --save core-js. But didnt work.

Comment: i guess you don't have the correct core-js version, try npm install core-js@2

Comment: I have installed it but not working

Comment: When I am deleting babel.config.js its working. How ?